# Javascript function issue

Tags: javascript

Hi i did some search about some function that i need , and i found it here on StackOverFlow .
The problem is in all browsers i get "bug" on the script that says :

```
mouse_is_inside is not defined
```

**But its defined ,and the function working perfect,** and can't get rid from that message any advance?

I tryed though of that . but i dont know how to assume :

```
if (typeof variable === 'undefined') {
    // variable is undefined
}
```

My function :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#contactbox').hover(function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=true; 
    }, function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=false; 
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function(){

        if(! mouse_is_inside)  // the problem is here says not defined .
            {
            if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7) {
                   $("#main").css('z-index','0');
                  } 
                  $('#contactb a').removeClass('cactive');
             $('#contactb a').addClass('cnoactive');
            $('#contactbox').hide()
            }
    });
});
```

**EDIT** thanks my bad , didnt know its so easy . i will tick the answer.

Comment: Haha , i will change sorry bad mispell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to add this line:

```
var mouse_is_inside = false;
```

...just inside the function. E.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var mouse_is_inside = false;
    // ...the rest of the code
});
```

Because the error is correct: You haven't defined it anywhere. But then the first time you do this:

```
mouse_is_inside=false;
```

or this:

```
mouse_is_inside=true;
```

...you're defining it, by falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). In JavaScript's "loose" mode (the default), if you try to *read* the value of an undefined symbol, it's a `ReferenceError`; but if you *write* to an undefined symbol, it creates a global variable (implicitly). Fortunately, as of ES5, we have "strict" mode which makes both operations the errors they should be.

Comment: But the variable it's global isn't it, sorry to doubt but I noticed that

Comment: @PlaceUserNameHere: Yes, it is -- it's an *implicit* global, because it's not defined anywhere, but the OP is assigning to it.

Comment: @Ravg: Easy mistake to make. Check out [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode), it's really useful to catch things like this (or typos, e.g., you declare the variable `blarg` but type `blagr` by mistake).

Answer (score 1):

Add declaration of `mouse_is_inside` i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mouse_is_inside;
    $('#contactbox').hover(function () {
        mouse_is_inside = true;
    }, function () {
        mouse_is_inside = false;
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function () {

        if (!mouse_is_inside) // the problem is here says not defined .
        {
            if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 7) {
                $("#main").css('z-index', '0');
            }
            $('#contactb a').removeClass('cactive');
            $('#contactb a').addClass('cnoactive');
            $('#contactbox').hide()
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just declare:

```
var mouse_is_inside
```

right after document ready